# how to identify and remove the header part of a dataframe from Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have written a code in python that takes input from different users and computes a few mathematical functions on the table input from excel. But the issue I'm not able to solve is that, the data from excel may contain some header part. For instance:

```
Company Name
Room No,
Building,
State,
Country, Pin

Register: Staff Details

ID     Name         Dept
--------------------------
01     John          HR
02     Viky        Accounts
...    ...           ...
...    ...           ...
```

When I take `read_excel` pandas taken in all rows along with the header part with address.  I can't do `find index of ID and drop above rows` because the ID may not be always on column 1. Also, as the input is from different users, I am not in a state to remove first 7 rows or do a `skip_row` on reading the excel. For some users the table may start from 8 row for some it may start from 13 row etc.

How can I extract the starting of the table in pandas?

Comment: you can set the ```header``` parameter to ```None``` while reading the file, ```df.read_excel(filename, header=None)```

Comment: After that how can I know what each column is? I tried ```header=None``` then we have ```.columns``` as numbers from 1 to 44. So say if I want to merge on ```Name or Dept``` I wont know which is that column. how can I ```.rename``` based on values in a row?

Comment: you can read the file again with the parameter nrows=1, so now you have a list of column names